# PHP script outputs images, headers show no cache + gzipping

Tags: php, apache, caching, gzip, html5boilerplate

I'm working on a project from the html5 boilerplate base. I call a PHP script to return a user's avatar image, using header() to set the content-type as appropriate ('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' are the only types I'm allowing).

When I request the image, the server is responding with a gzipped, no-cache response:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Cache-Control:public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 11 Mar 2013 09:18:23 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=92
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

This is obviously not ideal... I am able to explicitly set the cache headers, but that doesn't address the root problem. If I set Content-Encoding: identity, it sends gzipped data anyway and the browser gets confused.

[The .htaccess file](https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/.htaccess)

...I just tested one other thing. I used ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off') in the PHP script, and also renamed the .htaccess file and I'm still getting the same result. I am truly baffled now. Server is running CentOS 5.9 with easyapache (sorry!)

How can I serve up images with the PHP script and apply the proper caching and compression rules to them?

Edit: The moment I posted this, I solved part of it of course... The gzip problem was some naive rules being set in one of the config files. Removing them allowed the .htaccess file to do its job, partly anyway. It's still disabling caching.

Comment: I know it's unhelpful, that's why I want to disable it :)

I thought that the .htaccess file should be setting the cache headers according to the response content type, but it doesn't appear to be doing that. (This is what I mean by not addressing the root problem -- unless I'm mistaken, I shouldn't have to be setting them explicitly?)

Comment: Ahh, you want to turn it *off*. Sorry, misunderstood that.

Comment: To address one part of your question - the cache headers you specify in the .htaccess file apply only to static resources that Apache serves itself. Them not being served for a PHP resource that happens to emit the same content type is normal AFAIK

Comment: Well that assuages my concern, then... thank you :)